# RSpec: Why doesn't let work but before(:each) does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have the current spec:

```
describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
  let(:client) { create(:client) }

  #before(:each) do
    #@client = create(:client)
  #end

  it "should delete a client" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, :id => client
    }.to change(Client, :count).by(-1)
  end

  # ...

end
```

The example fails when I use `let` but works fine when I use `before(:each)`.

Here is the implementation code:

```
def destroy
  client = Client.find(params[:id])
  if client.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Client deleted successfully"
    redirect_to kong_clients_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Client not deleted for some reason"
    redirect_to kong_clients_url
  end
end
```

So why does the example fail when I use let?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`let` is lazy-evaluated, the record isn't created until you access the `client` property inside the expect/lambda (+1), but then it's immediately deleted (-1), so overall inside the expectation the count doesn't change.

You can use `let!` to force it to evaluate straight away:

```
let!(:client) { create(:client) }
```